# How to add the filepath to a specified line of a file using bash script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I have the following bash code:

```
    echo "Enter an input path"
    read -e input_path

    OLDTEXT="\put(0,0){\includegraphics{/"
    NEWTEXT="\put(0,0){\includegraphics{$input_path/"

    find . -name "*.tex" -print0 | xargs -0  sed -i '$NEWTEXT' -e '$OLDTEXT'
```

The sed line always produces an error. This version of the code is producing the following error message:

sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `O'

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
oldtext='[\]put(0,0){[\]includegraphics{/'
newtext="\\\\put(0,0){\\\\includegraphics{$input_path/"
```

Also, `-i` and `-e` do not do what you expect. Try:

```
sed "s|$oldtext|$newtext|" file
```

If the above gives what your want, then use `-i` to change the file in place:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec sed -i "s|$oldtext|$newtext|" {} \;
```

With GNU `find` or a modern BSD `find`, it is more efficient to use:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec sed -i "s|$oldtext|$newtext|" {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense: `sed -i '$NEWTEXT' -e '$OLDTEXT'` -- even if you were properly using double quotes so the variables could be expanded, the values are not valid sed commands.

I assume you're trying to search and replace:

```
sed -i "s#$OLDTEXT#$NEWTEXT#"
```